# API bug? Video thumbnails no longer being returned in v3 API as of Mar 21

Tags: youtube-api

Per the v3 API [spec](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), videos that come back in searches should contain thumbnails.

Up until 30 minutes ago, that was the case.

However, now, the API is returning videos with no "thumbnails" attribute in the JSON.

For example:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=(key)&id=Kq9z1gNjl0o

Previously would return:

```
{

    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"idnvT0N6oxG_2o6LCWUdZsqtqtk/flm_N0PUouBHj2piDWTowbpXlNM\"",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "Kq9z1gNjl0o",
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"idnvT0N6oxG_2o6LCWUdZsqtqtk/9f5tPPIkXNmECTi095h9jBWV0s0\"",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2010-06-27T00:07:30.000Z",
                "channelId": "UC3lizSW-J9kc8JR455mzv-w",
                "thumbnails": [
                   "small": {
                        "url": "http://ytimg.com/someimage.jpg"
                    }
                ]
                "title": "Kristen Bell - On Craig Ferguson - 4/19/08 - Wow",
                "description": "Interview",
                "channelTitle": "stewiefan33",
                "categoryId": "22"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now returns:

```
{

    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"idnvT0N6oxG_2o6LCWUdZsqtqtk/flm_N0PUouBHj2piDWTowbpXlNM\"",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "Kq9z1gNjl0o",
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "\"idnvT0N6oxG_2o6LCWUdZsqtqtk/9f5tPPIkXNmECTi095h9jBWV0s0\"",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2010-06-27T00:07:30.000Z",
                "channelId": "UC3lizSW-J9kc8JR455mzv-w",
                "title": "Kristen Bell - On Craig Ferguson - 4/19/08 - Wow",
                "description": "Interview",
                "channelTitle": "stewiefan33",
                "categoryId": "22"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The "thumbnails" field is gone, but still in the doc. Is this a bug in the API?

Comment: I noticed this as well and can confirm.  However, it is an Experimental specification and can change at any time.

Comment: This is a big, we're fixing it. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed. Thanks guys.